# No me arranca en mi navegador explore

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hola a tod@s me gustaría poder iniciar mi navegador explore y me da error
este es mi código de java

```
public class Explore {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // se usa para definir la capacidad de IE 
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "IE");
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.
          INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

        String project = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", project + "\\drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        // se utiliza para inicializar el controlador 
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    }

}
```

He probado también quitando el capabilities y tampoco puedo navegar
esta es mi codigo de error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: No matching capability sets found.
Unable to match capability set 0: browserName must be 'internet explorer', but was 'IE'
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'quitado', ip: 'quitado', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
```

Comment: Claramente *browserName must be 'internet explorer'*. Te lo ha dicho.

Comment: si pero la ruta la tengo bien

Comment: @ManuelGarcia ¿seguro?

Comment: @NicolasOñate , si he probado con el chrome y si me funciona

Answer (score 1):

A mi si me funciona con este código y ni siquiera lo apunte al driver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);  
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, false);
capabilities.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);     
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.FORCE_CREATE_PROCESS, true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: gracias ya me funciona

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta que mas te ayudo haciendo click en la palomita.